# Py3o.template : How to format HTML variables from Odoo 13

Tags: python, html, odoo, odoo-13, libreoffice-writer

I'm working on .odt report using py3o.template in Odoo with LibreOffice Writer.
In the report, I get variables from Odoo 13 :

[image: Variable in LibreOffice Writer]

These variables contain HTML code. So the result contains HTML tags :

[image: Result in report]

Is it possible that the HTML code of the variable is interpreted in order to obtain a correct display ? With a Python function ?

Thank you !

Comment: Did you find a solution to the issue? I want to export descriptions fields.